# Access a split cell in word Table through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a 5x7 table in a Word document, and the 7th column is split in to 5 rows. How can I access each row of this split cell through VBA?

Example table :
[image: Example table]

Comment: Your question talks of *split* cells but your picture shows *merged* cells. The simple truth is that you lose the ability to access columns to the right of the merge in a table that has horizontally merged cells and the ability to access rows below the merge in a table that has vertically merged cells. The table in your picture has horizontally and vertically merged cells starting from Cell(1, 1). Therefore the only cell you may be able to address individually would be Cell(1, 1). Work around the problem by having 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

When you split a cell that way, each row becomes a new row in the table. Hence, you'd address the cells in column 7 as if there was no split. The first row below the split is row 6 - for all columns. The following macro will help you identify any selected cell's (or cells') address/range in the table:

```
Sub CellRange()
Dim StrAddr As String
' This macro displays the address of a table's selected cell range
' and the table's last cell address on Word's Status Bar (Word 2010 & earlier)
' or in a Message Box (Word 2013 & later)
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    StrAddr = "The selected "
    If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
      StrAddr = StrAddr & "cell address is: "
    Else
      StrAddr = StrAddr & "cells span: "
    End If
    StrAddr = StrAddr & ColAddr(.Cells(1).ColumnIndex) & .Cells(1).RowIndex
    If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
      StrAddr = StrAddr & ":" & ColAddr(.Characters.Last.Cells(1).ColumnIndex) & _
        .Characters.Last.Cells(1).RowIndex
    End If
    With .Tables(1).Range
      StrAddr = StrAddr & ". The table's last cell is at: " & _
        ColAddr(.Cells(.Cells.Count).ColumnIndex) & .Cells(.Cells.Count).RowIndex
    End With
  Else
    StrAddr = "The selection is not in a table!"
  End If
End With
If Int(Application.Version) < 15 Then
  StatusBar = StrAddr
Else
  MsgBox StrAddr, vbOKOnly
End If
End Sub

Function ColAddr(i As Long) As String
If i > 26 Then
  ColAddr = Chr(64 + Int(i / 26)) & Chr(64 + (i Mod 26))
Else
  ColAddr = Chr(64 + i)
End If
End Function
```